# Change Edit Account Information Layout

Tags: layout

How to change the layout of Change Account Information page ( `/customer/account/edit/` )? By default it uses **2columns-left.phtml**. I tried the following in **local.xml** but nothing changes:

```
<customer_account_edit translate="label">
    <reference name="customer_edit">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_edit>
```

What did I miss?

Also, how to change the layout of the following pages ?

- `/customer/address/edit/`
- `/customer/address/new/`
- `/customer/account/edit/changepass/1/`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rapter.
Please change the `reference` name  `customer_edit` to `root`.According to magento Page 
layout is change on root block reference

final:

```
<customer_account_edit translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_edit>
```

See at My [blog](http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-change-page-layout-in-magento/)

Comment: Yes, it works! But do I know the layout handle of the other pages listed in the question?

Comment: for magento defaultly,create a handler using it it routername_controllername_actionname.so just check current page router change it accordingly

Comment: I tried `<customer_address_edit>` for `/customer/address/edit/`, but no effect. why?